# aligning the JQuery UI tabs to bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I have a page where I am using JQuery tabs. Below is the screen shot that explains my problem clearly.

***Issue1***:The JQuery Tab div section is aligned to center and I want to set the entire tab section to occupy the 100% of the bottom section first( Marked in green in the Image)

***Issue2:*** the tab is over lapping with my horizontal dropdown menu's(marked in yellow in the Image). How can I make the dropdown menu to over lap the div's and float on top of every layer.

Note: I am using tiles for my application. The Menu section what in some other jsp page and the tab section was mapped to **body** attribute of the tiles

Here is my Tiles definitions

```
   <definition name="baseLayout" template="/BaseLayout.jsp">
       <put-attribute name="title" value="Hello World"/>
       <put-attribute name="header" value="/Banner.jsp"/>
       <put-attribute name="menu" value="/Menu.jsp"/>
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/Body.jsp"/>
       <put-attribute name="footer" value="/Footer.jsp"/>
   </definition>
```

.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overlap the menu with increasing the 'z-index' of your submenu in css. For the tab height, you can use jquery to assign height to tab or change page background to white. So the tab merged with page.

Comment: thank you so much. The overlapping of submenu issue is fine now after using 'z-index'. But regarding the 2nd issue I was able to fill the bottom section after increasing the size of the div but would like to achieve this with out increasing the size of the div. Please suggest if there is any other way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

This link addresses your issue:

http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/Easy-vertical-and-bottom-tab-panels-with-jQuery-UI

Comment: I am sorry but I don't want my Tab names to come down. I am just to trying to move the entire tab section to bottom of the page. As you can see the white coloured section was the tab section and it is occupying the upper part of the page first leaving some unused space  at the bottom(coloured in blue). So I want to make the div section to occupy the lower part first. Hope this explains my Issue clearly